# Where TeamViewer keeps the ID?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote, remote-access, remote-control, teamviewer

I'm using TeamViewer 9. I need to find where it holds ID and get it. I tried to find it in the regedit but i didn't find it. What can you advise me? I need to find id and send it to my gate.php or i need to create static id with TeamViewerQT.

Comment: Does [Is there a way to find a Teamviewer ID in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17166717) help?

Comment: [Script to find TeamViewer IDs across domain](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/104147-script-to-find-teamviewer-ids-across-domain)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did find it in the registry

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version9

ClientID

It was in Hexadecimal.  Once converted that was my TeamViewerID

I hope this helps.

Comment: How to convert something like this:
c3 fa 88 ce b3 1b 89 a6 6d b6 e1 73 66 82 68 52 61 c3 be 66 fd f8 e6 c0 5b 98 80 87 27 eb 00 e6 58 1b 64 24 4d de ce d0 a9 1e 9c 24 25 ea 79 7d 9b 09 7d 66 ec 77 25 75 e7 a1 3e 4a 15 5c 76 47 2d 03 74 f2 f9 62 ad ea 44 f9 8d bf 67 85 21 0d e8 35 52 ff 86 21 16 28 2e d3 a0 7e 50 63 f1 04
Into a number? It's very long line...

Comment: I am not sure why your string is so long.  For my clientid it was short.  You would convert the hex to decimal.  Since your original question mentioned php you could use hexdec to convert the value.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution might be correct in some cases, however the ClientID can be located in other locations in the Registry.

1. It depends on whether or not you are using a 64-bits OS. On 64-bits OS you need to include \Wow6432\.
2. Sometimes the registry location ends with a version (for example \Version9), but I have seen cases where it doesn't.

Possible locations:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer\Version[version]
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TeamViewer
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TeamViewer\Version[version]
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TeamViewer\Version